# Start at the same time processes python3

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I'm trying to simulate a producer-consumer design in Python 3 multiprocessing. The main problem is that the producer starts but the consumer doesn't start until the producer finishes (in this scenario, the consumer doesn't start because the producer never ends).

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from scapy.all import *
from queue import Queue
from multiprocessing import Process

queue = Queue()

class Producer(Process):
    def run(self):
        global queue
        print("Starting producer thread")
        sniff(iface="wlan1mon", store=0, prn=pkt_callback)

def pkt_callback(pkt):
    queue.put(pkt)
    print(queue.qsize())

class Consumer(Process):
    def run(self):
        global queue
        while True:
            pkt = queue.get()
            queue.task_done()
            if pkt.haslayer(Dot11):
                print("**Packet with Dot11 layer has been processed")
            else:
                print("--Packet without Dot11 layer has been processed")



if __name__ == '__main__':
    Producer().start()
    Consumer().start()
```

I don't know what's wrong in my code. I test it using multithreading and it works, so I guess there's something I misunderstood about multiprocessing.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure your queue is a shared memory object. I think your producer is writing to a queue in its memory and your consumer is reading from a queue in its memory, but they aren't the same memory so they aren't talking to each other. I think you need a "manager" wrapped around it. see the docs. https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes

Or use the multiprocessing version of a Queue. Again from the docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes

Comment: You're right, the two processes were not sharing memory. I just change it and I use now the multiprocessing version of Queue, and it works. But now I found another issue -.- Thank you @RobertB
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 234, in _feed
    obj = ForkingPickler.dumps(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 50, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function RadioTap.<lambda> at 0x7f41facf29d8>: attribute lookup RadioTap.<lambda> on scapy.layers.dot11 failed

Comment: Maybe start a new question for the new problem. Hard to read in a comment. I'm guessing there is a data type mismatch between what your queue is expecting and what the sniff is returning in your callback. I'm guessing that sniff is returning an object, then the multiprocessing.Queue object is trying to pickle it and send it to the other process. The pickling is failing because pickle doesn't like the sniff object. Pickling is a type of serialization. The queue object requires the input to be "pickleable" (per the docs.)

Comment: ... you can either change sniff to return something pickleable, or you have to pre/post process the object into something that *is* pickleable. I'm not familiar with scapy so I can't say.

Comment: Thank you again @RobertB. I'm going to try using the original Scapy3k implementation and creating a Manager, I would prefer not to modify Scapy :)